# Dataframe conversion using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

we have the following dataframe .

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a1 =["school.bgs.id","school.bgs.title","school.bgs.city","school.bgs.bgs1.id","school.sggs.id","school.sggs.title","school.sggs.city","school.sggs.srt.title","school.sggs.state"]
a2=[55,"BGS","pune",34,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
a3=[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,230,"SGGS","Nanded","SRT","maharashtra"]
df =pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a1,a2,a3)),columns=['data',0,1])
```

and expected output:

[image]

Kindly suggest better solution for the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you've asked:

```py
df['new_row'] = df.data.str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.')
df['new_col'] = df.data.str.split('.').str[-1]
df['new_val'] = df[0].where(df[0].notna(), df[1])
df = df.pivot('new_row','new_col','new_val')[['id','title','city','state']].rename_axis(None, axis='columns').rename_axis(None, axis='index')
```

Output:

```
                  id title    city        state
school.bgs        55   BGS    pune          NaN
school.bgs.bgs1   34   NaN     NaN          NaN
school.sggs      230  SGGS  Nanded  maharashtra
school.sggs.srt  NaN   SRT     NaN          NaN
```

Explanation:

- take the final dot-separated token within the `data` column as `new_col` and the corresponding prefix from `data` as `new_row`
- take the value of column `0` if non-null, else that of column `1`, as `new_val`
- use `pivot()` to create the desired output, with columns reordered using `[['id','title','city','state']]` and axis names removed using `rename_axis()`.

Answer (score 2):

using pivot looks quite suitable, so this solution is very similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73788280/18344512):

```
df[['data','col']] = df['data'].str.rsplit('.',1,expand=True)
df = df.assign(val=df[0].combine_first(df[1])).pivot('data','col','val')
```

and the result is:

```
col                city   id        state title
data                                           
school.bgs         pune   55          NaN   BGS
school.bgs.bgs1     NaN   34          NaN   NaN
school.sggs      Nanded  230  maharashtra  SGGS
school.sggs.srt     NaN  NaN          NaN   SRT
```

Answer (score 1):

Another rather similar way is as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df[['data', 'cols']] = df['data'].str.extract(r'(?P<data>[\w.]+)\.(?P<cols>\w+$)')

df = (pd.pivot(df, index = 'data', columns='cols', values=[0, 1])
      .stack(level=0)
      .droplevel(1))

cols               city   id        state title
data                                           
school.bgs         pune   55          NaN   BGS
school.bgs.bgs1     NaN   34          NaN   NaN
school.sggs      Nanded  230  maharashtra  SGGS
school.sggs.srt     NaN  NaN          NaN   SRT
```